# email.send() taking forever for manual connection

Tags: python, django, django-1.4, django-email

## django 1.4 version

I know about send_email. But, I need to set manual connection for every email from db so using send() function.

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, get_connection

e = EmailMessage('sub', 'body', to=['to@email.com'])
```

Now, it uses default connection.

I want to set connection at this point, so I did this:

```
e.connection =    get_connection(backend='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend', username='email@gmail.com', password='password', host='smtp.gmail.com', port=465, use_tls=True)

e.send() #taking forever(means hanging there without moving to next command) Why ?
```

Am I clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the port argument to `get_connection()` from `port=465` (SSL) to `port=587` (TLS).

Comment: I just found that too, thanks for the answer, +1. But, those port number used to work a month back, what happened now ? Oh, 465 when I use ssl and 587 when I use tls ?

Comment: @user2349115:  AFAIK nothing has changed at the gmail end. Perhaps you were using SSL previously?

Comment: I donno I am confused. Current settings are  ssl to true, and port set to 465. Ofcourse, now I changed to  ssl false, tls true, and port to 587 which is working. Thanks for the answer.